# How to pass eval(ID) from a listview to a modal popup on asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a listview with multiple rows on it. i want that when the user clicks on one of the rows, a modal pop up shows up with the details of that row.

this is the aspx page:

```
<div id="listviewUsers">
    <asp:ListView ID="lvwusuarios" runat="server">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="Table1" runat="server" class="TableCSS">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" class="TableHeader">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">ID user</td>
                    <td id="Td9" runat="server">Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server" id="UsrRow" class="TableData" onclick='showModal()'>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label
                        runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("iduserno")%>'> 
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label
                        runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'> 
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
</div>


<div class="w3-container">
    <div id="modalusr" class="w3-modal">
        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-opacity" style="max-width: 600px">

            <form class="w3-container">
                <div class="w3-section">
                    <input type="text" readonly="true" id="txtusrid" value="HERE IS WHERE THE ID IS SUPPOSED TO SHOW UP" name="txtusrid" />

                    <input type="text" readonly="true" id="txtusrname" value="HERE IS WHERE THE NAME IS SUPPOSED TO SHOW UP" name="txtusrname" />

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function showModal() {
    document.getElementById("modalusr").style.display = "block";
}
```

I'm still trying to figuring out how to pass the eval(ID) on click event of every row to the modal when it show up. but i still can't figure out how to make it work. I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: have you tried passing the as parameters to your `showModal` function like this? `onclick='showModal(<%# Eval("iduserno")%>, <%# Eval("name")%>)'` then updating it to this: `function showModal(id, name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the ID as a parameter in `showModal`. But for that to work you need to remove the runat=server from the TR. You probably do not need that anyway.

```
<tr id="UsrRow" class="TableData" onclick="showModal(<%# Eval("iduserno") %>)">
```